# Gap between new ceiling tile and stone fireplace

Tags: gap

We removed 12x12 acoustic ceiling tiles that were stapled in. Put up Armstrong track system to install new tiles. The new tile lays from 1 inch to 2 inches above fireplace. It is a stone fireplace with many different sized stones. So not a flat surface.
Contractor was going to try and scribe wood trim to fill in gap. We're not happy with that look and not confident that she can do it. Any other ideas would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: pictures would be needed to understand your question

Answer (score 0):

You've basically got 2 choices:

1. Scribe some sort of material to match the stonework.
2. Have a straight edge (presumably the aluminum track) along the front of the fireplace, leaving gaps where the stone doesn't meet the track.

It seems you don't think you'll like the scribed look - maybe you should ask your contractor if one of her previous clients has a similar setup that you could see in person so you'll know for sure.

If you don't like the look of scribed, you're pretty much stuck with straight.